# Find whether given files exist in a directory

Tags: perl, directory, file-exists

I want to know whether a file exists or not in a given directory.

I need to find certain .txt files in the temporaryPath, but the directory of the files need to suit the pattern, I need to know whether the files exist or not in the given pattern as I think this is the fastest way to find the file, the only "uncertain" or ".*" path is between a/b/c/d/e/ and dou/you/1.txt, if I try to find with normal using Find::File under a parent directory a/b/c/d/e/, it will take about 10 mins and there is a chance that I stored unwanted path in the array cause 1.txt is also exist in subdirectories.

e.g. Wanted specific directories

```
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/dou/you/1.txt
a/b/c/d/e/k/l/m/dou/you/1.txt

a/b/c/d/e/k/l/m/wanna/play/2.txt
a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/wanna/play/2.txt

a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/with/me/3.txt
a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/with/me/3.txt
```

#### Perl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @temporaryPath = qw(
    dou/you/1.txt
    wanna/play/2.txt
    with/me/3.txt
    like/play/4.txt
    anything/really/5.txt
);

foreach my $temporaryList ( @temporaryPath ) {

    my $dir = "a/b/c/d/e/" . "*" . "/$temporaryList";

    if ( -e $dir ) {
        print " exist :) $temporaryList\n";
    }
    else {
        print " not exist :( $temporaryList\n";
    }
}
```

I used `.*` in `$dir` because there are a lot of different directories in between the path full path
, e.g. `f/g/h`, `k/l/m`, or `z/x/c`.

The result is this

```
not exist :( dou/you/1.txt
not exist :( wanna/play/2.txt
not exist :( with/me/3.txt
not exist :( like/play/4.txt
not exist :( anything/really/5.txt
```

meaning that the `$dir` can not read `a/b/c/d/e/.*/`

Is there any way?

Comment: Sounds like you want to see if particular files are somewhere in a directory tree but don't know the exact paths to them? If so, [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) is your friend.

Comment: @Shawn, I know where the directory is, I just want to know whether its possible to use .* in the middle of the path and why I can't declare my path in $dir. If I use Find::File, it will search all required files in the sub directory in the parent directory, and these files has the same name in the sub directories.

Comment: Okay. `-e` and everything else that takes a filename requires a path, relative or absolute, to a file. No wildcards like a shell would expand.

Comment: @Shawn, if I want to find the file that I want in this parent directory, a/b/c/d/e/ , the time taken is so long. for example, my @ files123 = File::Find::Rule->file()
       ->name( '1.txt' )
                            ->in( 'a/b/c/d/e/' );
and there is a risk, that i gain the directory path that I don't want. I want the file must be in this parent folder a/b/c/d/e/ and in this folder dou/you/1.txt , the full path should be a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/dou/you/1.txt or a/b/c/d/e/k/l/m/dou/you/1.txt or  a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/dou/you/1.txt  , the file 1.txt must have in one of the these full path.

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] your question and include a set of example directories and files with an explanation which ones exactly you want to find and which you don't.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. We need to see some examples.

Comment: @simbabque , example like? I already put it in the question above, I need to find certain .txt files in the temporaryPath, but the directory of the files need to suit the pattern, I need to know whether the files exist or not in the given pattern as I think this is the fastest way to find the file, the only "uncertain" or ".*" path is between  a/b/c/d/e/ and dou/you/1.txt, if I try to find with normal using Find::File under a parent directory  a/b/c/d/e/, it will take about 10 mins and there is a chance that I stored unwanted path in the array cause 1.txt  is also exist in subdirectories.

Comment: @Danial: Please don't add parts of the question to your code as comments.

Comment: @Danial: I agree with **simbabque**. You say *"there are a lot of different directories and I don't care about these"*, so we really need to see examples of file paths that you want to include and those that you want to ignore.

Comment: @Danial: You've rejected answers [from **ikegami**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52426040/622310) and [from me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52426183/622310) for disparate reasons. It's looking more like your problem is more to do with general computer knowledge than with a specific Perl problem, and I think your post is off topic for Stack Overflow. I've had to make several changes to your code so that I could read it clearly, and I hope that you will use a more consistent format in the future.

Comment: I'm really grateful that there are peoples that are willing to give their time and attention to answer my scripting problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`-e` is correctly reporting that there is no file with path `a/b/c/d/e/*/dou/you/1.txt` because there's no directory named `*` in `a/b/c/d/e`.

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

my @targets = qw(
    dou/you/1.txt
    wanna/play/2.txt
    with/me/3.txt
    like/play/4.txt
    anything/really/5.txt
);

my $base_dir_qfn = 'a/b/c/d/e';

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file->in($base_dir_qfn);

my $target_pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @targets;
my $target_re = qr{/(?:$target_pat)\z};

for my $file (@files) {
   say $file if $file =~ $target_re;
}
```

Test:

```
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/dou/you;    touch a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/dou/you/1.txt
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/k/l/m/dou/you;    touch a/b/c/d/e/k/l/m/dou/you/1.txt
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/k/l/m/wanna/play; touch a/b/c/d/e/k/l/m/wanna/play/2.txt
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/wanna/play; touch a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/wanna/play/2.txt
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/with/me;    touch a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/with/me/3.txt
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/with/me;    touch a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/with/me/3.txt
$ perl a.pl
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/dou/you/1.txt
a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/with/me/3.txt
a/b/c/d/e/k/l/m/dou/you/1.txt
a/b/c/d/e/k/l/m/wanna/play/2.txt
a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/wanna/play/2.txt
a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/with/me/3.txt
```

Comment: Hey @ikegami , thank you for your solution, care to explain this?my $target_pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @targets;
my $target_re = qr{/(?:$target_pat)\z};

Comment: i tried to run with your script above, but strangely enough it doesnt search through all the folder, for example it only go through "a/b/c/d/e/k/l/m/$temporaryList" when I say $file if not $file =~ $target_re;  , supposedly it must search through "a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/$temporaryList" also, because the file only exist in f/g/h directory, why when I print out, it only search for certain folders only, note that, I have hundred directories, and directories such as f/g/h k/l/m and z/x/c is just examples.

Comment: It builds a regex pattern. Print `$target_re` and see.

Comment: It searches through every subfolder of `a/b/c/d/e`. Contrary to your claim, it *will* find `a/b/c/d/e/z/x/c/dou/you/1.txt`

Comment: I still can't find the file. have tried different directory, it still doesnt search through a/b/c/d/e/f/  and a/b/c/d/e/k/, it only search in 1 directory per 1 directory, let say, there is this directories a/b/c/d/e/f/  , a/b/c/d/e/z/ , a/b/c/d/e/k/ and a/b/c/d/e/v/ in the first parent directory, and in the subdirectory of a/b/c/d/e/f/ , there is a/b/c/d/e/f/g ,  a/b/c/d/e/f/q ,  a/b/c/d/e/f/w, it just search 1 directory per level.

Comment: I already found the problem, i tried to print files, it turns out that the directory is not there in the array, the folder is there , and when i tried symlink, my files (i cant put shift 2 due this comment editor) = File::Find::Rule->file->symlink->in($base_dir_qfn); , it is still not there, what is the problem, the folder is really exist, but it doesnt exist in the array.

Comment: You've provided absolutely no information to show it doesn't work, and the the test I just added to my answer shows that it does work.

Comment: is there any other type of directory beside normal directory and symbolic links? because File::Find can't find wanted directory.

Comment: Symlinks aren't directories. I don't know what you mean by type of directories. And I can't help you if you provide absolutely no information about your problem.

Comment: I have update the question above, I know symlinks are not directories, how can I explain this, the path itself contains whether symlinks and directories, but the folder is there, existed, there is subdirectories inside it, but when I use Find::File, it can't recognize it.

Comment: You update makes things clearer, but doesn't change the question at all; the answer is still the same

Comment: thank you. I know, the answer is the same, and I really grateful to you and Borodin.

Comment: In you question, you said you wanted to search subdirectories. Are you now saying you also want to follow symlinks? If so, please adjust the question

Comment: no no, I mean, I can't find the directories that I want using File::Find, and it is not symlinks and also directories, which is weird.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need the
[`File::Globstar`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Globstar) module. It implements the equivalent of the shell *globstar* extension which will allow two asterisks `**` in the pattern to match any string, including path separators

It could look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use File::Globstar 'globstar';

my @paths = qw{
    dou/you/1.txt
    wanna/play/2.txt
    with/me/3.txt
    like/play/4.txt
    anything/really/5.txt
};

for my $path ( @paths ) {

    say for globstar "a/b/c/d/e/**/$path;
}
```

Comment: I tried to download File::Globstar and use lib 'somepath' , but this problem emerged,"dpgettext" is not exported by the Locale::Messages module ,"dnpgettext" is not exported by the Locale::Messages module, I have googled it but found no solution. @Borodin

Comment: Sounds like your version of Locale::Messages could be out of date. Run `perl -MLocale::Messages\ 99` on your terminal and tell us which version number it says. The newest one is 1.29. However, that's quite unlikely, as [it was added in 2008](https://github.com/gflohr/libintl-perl/commit/bb704c9a3b9b33a59ff0195707cfd3c91a6f5852) and must have gone in in 1.17 if I read the github release page correctly.

Comment: @simbabque , I tried to run, but it can't locate it because I use , use lib"", to store the globstar module in my download folder, and I cant add it to Perl directory, there is restriction.

Comment: @DanialHaris add the `-I=<your lib directory>` flag (captial i) to the command to add an additional `lib`.

Comment: @Danial: Computer programs can be hard to describe, and you need to be as unambiguous as possible. Stack Overflow provides *Markdown* to format your posts, and you should use it to the fullest extent to explain yourself clearly. There is an excellent help page [**Markdown Editing Help**](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and you should study and apply it.

Comment: @simbabque, you are correct, the module that I downloaded is outdated, Locale::Messages, the problem is fixed.